# How to resize my xml so that it will fit nicely on the emulator

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am currently having trouble with my GUI design because of the whole page will be shifted to the right and become like this:

[image]

create_events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/crimson"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Title:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Location:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Start At:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="End At:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Alarm:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAlarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="Set Alarm" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMain"
        style="@style/main_menu"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_load_picbutton"
        android:text="Main Menu" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEvent"
        style="@style/main_menu"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnMain"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnMain"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_load_picbutton"
        android:text="Create Event" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I do not know the reason as to why the whole screen is shifted. The last time I opened, it was fits in the screen perfectly. Anyone has any idea why, can you please help me? Thanks.

Edited:

[image]

After doing according to what @Andy Res said, My screen currently is displayed like this. For your reference, the skin that I am using for my emulator is WVGA854.

Comment: try layout_gravity for the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you allign your `Title` to the right of `txtDate`.
And then all the controls are aligned having the `Title` as a reference.

So I believe this line may cause the shifting to the right.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtDate"
        .... />
```

Try to remove: `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtDate"` and see if any effect.

Comment: Hi I have commented out that part of the xml and the whole screen shifted to the middle but it is still a bit off. I have added the screenshot of the screen after commenting out that part of the code. Can you please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Your `Spinner` and location `EditText` are not aligned properly. If you take a look at other controls you'll see they have an attribute ` android:layout_toRightOf=""`. But these 2 controls have missing these attribute. So, to fix it align them properly to the right of their corresponding label.